# DataTables with Asp.net Web Service

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to load data to DataTables from database calling simple web service. For some reason I have 500 Internal Server Error .
I have tested web service and it returns data as expected. Thanks

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string DataFromDB()
{
    scansedDBEntities _db = new scansedDBEntities();
    var query = from p in _db.Names
                select p;

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
}
```

and JavaScript:

```
 $('#tblNames').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "../SSService.asmx/DataFromDB",
     }
});
```

Comment: DataTables - or any other javascript runned on the client - can not cause a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: That's right. Response body says: "Invalid JSON primitive". Still don't know how to fix it though